# Problem with BindableProperty on custom control

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm having problems binding text to a label inside a custom control.

I have made the following control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Frida3.Components.TestView">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
      </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

With the following code-behind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class TestView : ContentView
{
    public TestView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TestView), default(string));

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string) GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

When using the control and a binding to set the Text property, nothing is shown. Below is some sample code of showing the results:

```
<!-- Shows that the LoginText binding contains value -->
<Label Text="{Binding LoginText}" BackgroundColor="BurlyWood"/>
<!-- Nothing shown with same binding -->
<components:TestView Text="{Binding LoginText}" BackgroundColor="Aqua" />
<!-- Works without binding -->
<components:TestView Text="This is showing" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
```

And here is the result of that:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You're setting the binding context here to the code behind file. So if my understanding is correct, it's looking at the CodeBehind for a property LoginText and failing because it doesn't exist. In the xaml, on the middle one, try setting BindingContext='{Binding ViewModel}' or alternatively, get rid of BindingContext assignment in the constructor.

Comment: @MaxHampton I tried removing the BindingContext assignment in the constructor, but the result was both Aqua and Yellow views were empty. I think that BindingContext is isolated inside that element, and is required for the binding on the Label.

Comment: Adding bindings for a custom control creates unnecessarily complex code and potentially affects performance. You're much better off using the `HandlePropertyChanged` event.

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure I exactly understand what you mean. Can you provide an example? How else to make reusable controls, if not for binding data to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XAML

Let's take the XAML of your custom control as below:

```xml
<ContentView 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Frida3.Components.TestView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Adding bindings to your custom control adds another level of complexity to your app, which may hinder the app's performance if used excessively. You are better off rewriting the `Label` as:

```xml
<Label x:Name="MyLabel"/>
```

Now, the `Label` is accessible in the code-behind.

### Code-Behind

You've set up the property correctly in your question as below:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
        "Text", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(TestView), 
        default(string));

public string Text
{
    get => (string) GetValue(TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
}
```

You can remove the `BindingContext = this;` from the constructor, because you won't be using any bindings.

In your `TextProperty`, we're going to add an event for the `propertyChanged` parameter, and define the event:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(Text), 
        returnType: typeof(string), 
        declaringType: typeof(TestView), 
        defaultValue: default(string),
        propertyChanged: HandleTextPropertyChanged); // Property-changed handler!!

public string Text
{
    get => (string) GetValue(TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
}

// Handler for when the Text property changes.
private static void HandleTextPropertyChanged(
    BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var control = (TestView)bindable;
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.MyLabel.Text = (string)newValue;
    }
}
```

What's happening here? Essentially, you've told the app

> "When the `Text` property of `TestView` changes, set the `Text`
>   property of `MyLabel` to the new string value".

Your code should now look like:

```cs
// BindableProperty for your Text property
public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(Text), 
        returnType: typeof(string), 
        declaringType: typeof(TestView), 
        defaultValue: default(string),
        propertyChanged: HandleTextPropertyChanged); // Property-changed handler!!

// Text property of you TestView
public string Text
{
    get => (string) GetValue(TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
}

// Constructor
public TestView ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
}

// Handler for when the Text property changes.
private static void HandleTextPropertyChanged(
    BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var control = (TestView)bindable;
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.MyLabel.Text = (string)newValue;
    }
}
```

You can now call your custom view like so:

```xml
<components:TestView 
    Text="This is showing" />

<components:TestView 
    Text="{Binding SomeOtherTextProperty}" />
```

There you have it! No bindings, just good old-fashioned events.

Comment: Aha! It just hit me that you probably meant like this. And then I came here to check if you replied, and you did - and confirmed my thoughts. Thank you for the in-depth answer!

Comment: I ran into another issue with this approach. Maybe it's worth posting another question about. But when the Text property has been set through an app-wide style, the Text property is being set on TestView before MyLabel has been instantiated, which results in a null reference exception on the line setting control.MyLabel.Text = (string)newValue;

Adding a null check, would probably mean the text property of the label will not end up with the value that I set in my style.

Comment: I thought I could cleverly change my component to be completely C#-based, but ran into the same issue. See more about the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523431/xamarin-forms-bindableproperty-changed-before-constructor
Where a suggested workaround is using bindings. I'm confused :D

Comment: I'm assuming as you've marked this as the correct answer you're no longer confused?

Comment: I guess I was a bit too quick on the correct answer button. In reality I am so far using the solution I posted on my own answer below. If you have a solution to the problems I posted regarding your answer, then I would love to see it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Basically I give my control a name (`x:Name="this"`), and I add a source to the data binding, like so: `Source={x:Reference this}`.
With these changes, I can remove `BindingContext = this;`

So the final xaml will be like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Frida3.Components.TestView"
             x:Name="this">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" />
      </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

I would like to know if there's a simpler way, so I don't have to add source to every single child that uses a BindableProperty..